# Numpy: Multiply several columns with one column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to multiply an array with lets say two columns with one column pairweise:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[1,2],[1,2]])
b=np.array([1,0])
```

And I want the output:

```
c=[[1,2][0,0]]
```

How is that possible?

Best regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this way using [`numpy.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2],[1,2]])
b = np.array([1,0])
c = a * b[:, np.newaxis]

# [[1 2]
# [0 0]]
```

Or you could just use:

```
c = a * b[:, None]
```

This is because `newaxis` is an alias for `None`.